# Reduce over integers - why does MMA not give ~impossible?

Tags: equation-solving

I know that Reduce is not Solve but from e.g. [212880](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/212880/using-reduce-over-integers-produces-weird-result) I also see that integer solutions may be found by it. However, I am clearly confused about what I should expect from it and why.

Consider this system of equations

$2^x = 3 k + 1 \land 2^{x-1} = 3 m + 1$

By inspection there are no solutions. If we put the question to MMA (11.0.1) like this

```
Block[{x, k, m}, Reduce[2^x == 3 k + 1 && 2^(x - 1) == 3 m + 1, {x, k, m}, Integers]]
```

We obtain (via TeXForm)

$ (k|m|x)\in \mathbb{Z}\land k=\frac{2^x}{3}-\frac{1}{3}\land
   m=\frac{2^{x-1}}{3}-\frac{1}{3}$

Q1 Why does MMA not realise that the forms of $k, m$ are incompatible?

Q2 Why does MMA state "$ (k|m|x)\in Integers$" as *Alternatives*? The reduction is specified over the integers so they must all be integers simultaneously. Specifically, why is it not expressed as an And of each $\in$ Integers?

Q3 Summary: is it basically just saying that there is no reduction of the equations?

NB if I reduce over {x, k}, or {x, m} MMA returns *False*, which I might interpret as there being no solution, but why should I pick these variable pairs? Note that Reduce over {k, m} does not return *False*

**UPDATE** Summary of new & selected points from various responses.

From the documentation, the first line of Details and Options, says that the result of Reduce" always describes exactly the same mathematical set as expr.", and a further example further down confirms  that False means there is no solution.

Ordering of variables is important: Reduce[..., {k, m, x}] = False i.e. it *does* give "~impossible".

Reduce *might*, like FindInstance be unable to provide an answer, but unlike the latter may not know that it can't and may not say so to the user.

From the documentation, $Element[x1|x2|...,dom]$ asserts that all the $x_i$ are elements of dom. (The justification for using this form to express is still wanting)

Note that $2^x$ is not integral for integer $x<0$

Comment: Q2: This is [well documented](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html). You can read it as follows: Whichever of the 3 alternatives (variables) you take, it is an integer.

Comment: Comment about Q1: `FindInstance[2^x==3 k+1&&2^(x-1)==3 m+1,{x,k,m},Integers]` returns no solution and says "The methods available to FindInstance are insufficient to find the requested instances or prove they do not exist." V12.3. Another example with similar behavior is `FindInstance[{2^a==2*b+1,b>0},{a,b},Integers]`.

Comment: @user293787 Did you perhaps mean the info on [Alternatives](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Alternatives.html)? (I checked it previously.) It functions as an "or" like construct, and, working inclusively includes all. The question is I suppose a language design question. Why not list the elements joined by And? Is there something that Alternatives enables that the And construction wouldn't?

Comment: @user293787 I also tried FindInstance but as you noted it actually says nothing -- didn't find an instance, doesn't mean they don't exist (though we know they don't), but the question is about Reduce really. Nice to have another example though.

Comment: No, I meant the info in [the documentation on Element, see the 3rd syntax there](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Element.html). It says "Element[x1|x2|...,dom] asserts that all the xi are elements of dom".

Comment: I mentioned `FindInstance` because it *does* say something: It explicitly admits that it does not know how to handle these types of equations. See the message I quoted. It seems plausible that `Reduce` has a similar limitation, even if it does not produce that message.

Comment: Not sure, but `Reduce[2^x == 3 k + 1 && 2^(x - 1) == 3 m + 1, {k, m, x}, Integers]` works. Polynomial  equations -- not ones with "transcendental" terms, or at least not with exponential terms -- are the principal domain of `Reduce`. Possibly `Reduce` does not analyze exponential terms unless "asked." The order of the variables matters in `Reduce`: The later variables are solved in terms of the earlier ones. You need `x` not to be first in the list.

Answer (score 6):

```
Reduce[2^x == 3 k + 1 && 2^(x - 1) == 3 m + 1, {x}, Integers]
```

> `False`

If we using `{x,k,m}` as variable, MMA will try to give all the expression of all the variable `{x,k,m}`,it maybe exceed the ability of MMA. If we only set `{x}`, MMA will refer `{k,m}` as parametric variables, this make it focus the relation between `{x}` and `{k,m}`,that is we need to help MMA in this cases.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with Mathematica in such a way.

```
NMinimize[{(2^x - 3 k - 1)^2 + (2^(x - 1) - 3 m - 1)^2, 
x \[Element] Integers && m \[Element] Integers &&  k \[Element] Integers}, {x, m, k}]
```

> `{0.25, {x -> 0, m -> 0, k -> 0}}`

The above result implies there is no solution of the system under consideration over the integers.

Addition. I think the result of (`y=2^x`)

```
FunctionConvexity[(y - 3 k - 1)^2 + (y/2 - 3 m - 1)^2, {y, k, m}]
```

> `1`

guarantees the found minimum over the integers is global.

Addition 2.

```
NMinimize[{(y - 3 k - 1)^2 + (y/2 - 3 m - 1)^2, {y, k, m} \[Element]  Integers}, {y, k, m}]
```

> `{0.25,{y->1,k->0,m->0}}`

implies `{0.25, {x -> 0, m -> 0, k -> 0}}` is the global minimum of `(2^x - 3 k - 1)^2 + (2^(x - 1) - 3 m - 1)^2` over the integers since the global minimum of the convex function over the superset $\mathbb Z^3$ equals the minimum over the set $\{2^x|x\in \mathbb Z\}\times\mathbb Z^2$. Hope I am clear.

Addition 3. As @user293787 pointed out, $2^x$  is not an integer if $x$ is a negative integer. For this case

```
NMinimize[{(y - 3 k - 1)^2 + (y/2 - 3 m - 1)^2, {k, m} \[Element] 
Integers && y > 0 && y <= 1}, {y, k, m}]
```

> `{0.25, {y -> 1., k -> 0, m -> 0}}`

completes the job.

Comment: But... `NMinimize[{(x^3+y^3-z^3)^2,Element[x|y|z,PositiveIntegers]},{x,y,z}]` returns `{1.,{x->1,y->1,z->1}}`. Do you consider that a proof of the $n=3$ case of [a famous theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem)? The documentation says: "If f and cons are linear or convex, the result given by NMinimize will be the global minimum, over both real and integer values; otherwise, the result may sometimes only be a local minimum. "

Comment: @user293787: Thank you for your valuable comment.  At least, the command `FunctionConvexity[(2^x - 3 k - 1)^2 + (2^(x - 1) - 3 m - 1)^2, {k, m},
  Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]` results in `1`.

Comment: The original function is only convex in $k,m$ but not in $k,m,x$. Convexity of your new function in $k,m,y$ does not imply convexity of the original function, since $y=2^x$ is not affine linear. Nevertheless, I agree that you will somehow be able to conclude in this way that there is no solution. I think that by introducing $y$ you are doing part of what OP probably had in mind when they wrote "By inspection there are no solutions". I did not know about `FunctionConvexity`. +1

Comment: @user293787: Please, see Addition 2, Don't hesitate to ask for further explanation in need.

Comment: Just to clarify, the question is fundamentally about how Reduce works; the non-existence of a solution can be established by various means. This minimisation trick is new to me - duly noted!

Comment: One more thing: $2^x$ is not an integer if $x$ is a negative integer.

Comment: @user293787: Thank you for your valuable comment.  See Addition 3.

Comment: Not buying this convexity argument. With a slight change: `In[15]:= FunctionConvexity[(2^x - 3 k - 2)^2 + (2^(x - 1) - 3 m - 
     1)^2, {k, m}, Assumptions -> x \[Element] Reals]

Out[15]= 1

In[13]:= NMinimize[{(2^x - 3 k - 2)^2 + (2^(x - 1) - 3 m - 1)^2, 
  x >= 1, k >= 0, m >= 0, {x, k, m} \[Element] Integers}, {x, k, m}]

Out[13]= {0., {x -> 1, k -> 0, m -> 0}}` But notice the solution is not unique. `In[14]:= (2^x - 3 k - 2)^2 + (2^(x - 1) - 3 m - 1)^2 /. {x -> 3, 
  m -> 1, k -> 2}

Out[14]= 0`